# Getting full user name siteminder

Tags: java, web-services, gwt-ext, siteminder

We are using GWT-EXT framework whereby on the toolbar i need to show the full user name of the user who logged in.

I could able to retrieve the user id via the request object from the custom made web services (in jars ) but i could not able to see any method which will give me a full user name.

I don't know anything about this custom made framework as everything is in jars and frustratingly opaque for the developer.

I searched few links and found that it is Siteminder agent which will inject the headers with key value pair which has user information in the request object  when it is redirected to the web application.
Now the question is how do i know what is the header which gives me a full user name.

The other part is to know how can i override the framework servlet /create my own servlet to retrieve this full header at the least.

I understand it is really vague question as even i am educating myself about the whole workflow and riddling my brain.

Really appreciate Any ideas or suggestions or advise  !

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your setup details like app environment, authentication and authorization modules used etc. Based on that I might be able to provide some inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about you setup. 
Siteminder agent by default do not return the logged in username. Siteminder Policy server needs to be instructed to return the required values in the response header after successful authentication. The Siteminder admin should be able to help you with this configuration.

Comment: Thanks Ramadan for your suggestion.
I have contacted siteminder support and they try to send the first name and last name headers.
Unfortunately the custom made webservices are not capturing these headers and storing them in session object which is why we could not able to see any methods with regards to users first and last name.